# Outlook 2010 cheaper/free replacement

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, scheduled-tasks, email-client, feed-reader

I am very pleased with Outlook 2010, but since I can't use it any more I have two big options: buy it or search for a decent cheaper/free replacement.

What I need from that program/suite is:

- POP/SMTP good management (I have Yahoo Mail Plus which uses SSL for SMTP and POP3 - not all clients support these)
- Task management
- RSS feed reading
- Calendar / scheduling

This is for personal use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-office-outlook/

Comment: Why can you no longer use it?  Honestly while Thunderbird and Lighting will be able to get close it will be nothing like Outlook.

Comment: Well it seems the activation code (cough, cough) doesn't work anymore...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm fearing, totally uncomparable alternatives. Mozilla produces (excuse me people) products below my quality standards.

Comment: I have been using Thunderbird for many years and have never had an issue with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is [Windows Live Mail 2011](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mail?os=other). It really looks nice and Outlook-ish ;)

[image: Windows Live Mail 2011]

It's practically Outlook Express revamped, nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/thunderbird/) + [Lightning](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/) extension (see picture below).

Thunderbird supports SMTP/POP3/IMAP with or without SSL, RSS feeds and Lightning adds tasks/calendars.

Furthermore Thunderbird is highly customizable through masses of useful [add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/?browse=featured).

[image]